# Attribute completion richfaces on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, richfaces

I have a problem with my web app on eclipse (helios). I use jsf with richfaces and I haven't the attributes completion for richfaces tag.

All work fine for jsf. I have the richfaces tags (rich:column for example) but when I do ctrl + space to see attribute on the tag, nothing appears.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your available update sites:

[JBoss Tools](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/)

Then install Jboss Tools Richfaces.

Once it's installed and you're restarted eclipse you'll need to right click on your project and choose "Configure" -> "Add JSF Capabilities".

Comment: I installed it but nothing change

Comment: after that you need to enable jsf capabilities. Right click on your project and choose Configure -> Add JSF Capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hi Kiva,

A few questions.  Are you using JSPs or XHTML/Facelets?  First I would check that the RichFaces namespace has been properly registered, no misspellings or typos, etc.  Then I would guess is if you're using XHTML to make sure that you're using the JBoss XHTML editor.  You can right-click the file in the package explorer and choose "Open with" to make sure that you're using the appropriate editor.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project -> Preferences -> Project Facets -> Click on "JavaServer Faces".

If you are still not able to see "OK" Button, please click on "Further Configuration Required" . Here you can add the JSF Implementation jar.

Now refresh your project.